# How can I set up omitting of space below caption at page bottom?

Tags: graphics, captions, positioning

I am using the `caption` package with:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{width=1\textwidth,font={small,{stretch=1.1}},aboveskip=1em, belowskip=2em}
```

The problem is `belowskip` generates extra space even if the image is placed at the bottom of a page. How can I solve this?

EDIT: Okay ,

```
\setlength\intextsep{2em}
```

solved the problem partially. The floats are now placed at the bottom but there is still space between captions and float-bottom.
Using

```
\belowcaptionskip
```

with negativ values helps but then

```
\setlength\textfloatsep{2em}
```

gives also a reduced height in text below figures

Comment: if the caption is at the bottom of your figures you should set belowskip to 0pt, it is the space below the caption before the figire or table within the float. space after the float should be handled separately, eg floatsep

Comment: That wouldnt solve the problem! adding vspace* inside each figure would solve the problem but unfortunately only locally

Comment: why would it not solve the problem? if there is no space below the caption within the float, and you specify the required space between floats and between floats and the main text then the page bottom should be handled correctly. If not please provide an example.